# cancel all proximity alerts

Tags: android

The `LocationManager` provides the method [removeProximityAlert(PendingIntent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeProximityAlert%28android.app.PendingIntent%29), but how does one remove a ProximityAlert (or simply all of them) when you no longer have a handle to the `PendingIntent`?  The GPS icon remains in the status bar, and I have set no expiration for the ProximityAlert.

Uninstalling the application that spawned it does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an equivalent `PendingIntent`, one of the same type (e.g., `getBroadcast()`) and wraps an equivalent `Intent` (i.e., one with the same action, data, type, and component -- whatever of that you set originally). Then, use this `PendingIntent` to remove your proximity alerts.

Also note that the GPS icon always stays on for the emulator; only on hardware will the GPS icon truly reflect the status of the GPS radio.

Comment: Thanks. I found the code that removes it: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=services/java/com/android/server/LocationManagerService.java#l1587  -- it uses a HashMap, but I was unsure whether two separate PendingIntent objects with identical member values would be distinct in the HashMap. I found the .equals() method of PendingIntent: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/app/PendingIntent.java;h=be1dc4acb150d6e6b3f20e136b0edcb2c3edaf60;hb=HEAD#l431-- it references the .asBinder() method... I stopped there.

Comment: @CommonsWare... life saver!...again