# Android - remove Proximity Alert after notification

Tags: android, service, alert, proximity

what I am trying to do is have a proximity alert service which triggers a notification ONLY ONCE when you step inside the radius (without stopping the service). my code triggers notifications every time you step inside the radius and every time you step outside the radius. i've been trying with booleans and with removeProximityAlert, but no success. any ideas?

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ProximityService extends Service {

    private String PROX_ALERT_INTENT = "com.example.proximityalert";
    private BroadcastReceiver locationReminderReceiver;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private PendingIntent proximityIntent;

 @override
    public void onCreate() {
        locationReminderReceiver = new ProximityIntentReceiver();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        double lat = 55.586568;
        double lng = 13.0459;
        float radius = 1000;
        long expiration = -1;

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
        registerReceiver(locationReminderReceiver, filter);

        Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);

        intent.putExtra("alert", "Test Zone");

        proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        locationManager.addProximityAlert(lat, lng, radius, expiration, proximityIntent);

    }

 @override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Proximity Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(locationReminderReceiver);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.d("receiver", e.toString());
        }

    }

 @override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Proximity Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

 @override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }



    public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;

     @suppressWarnings("deprecation")
     @override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

            String place = arg1.getExtras().getString("alert");

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(arg0, 0, arg1, 0);

            Notification notification = createNotification();

            notification.setLatestEventInfo(arg0, "Entering Proximity!", "You are approaching a " + place + " marker.", pendingIntent);

            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

            locationManager.removeProximityAlert(proximityIntent);

        }

        private Notification createNotification() {
            Notification notification = new Notification();

            notification.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
            notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

            return notification;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to remove pendingIntent instead of proximityIntent maybe since its already passed through it that different context now

Comment: i read using String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
   
   Boolean entering = arg1.getBooleanExtra(key, false); in onRecieve and the using if(entering){}else{} is for entering and exiting, i couldnt get it to work though

Comment: yes, that would check for entering and exiting, but it still notifies each time. the answer was probably [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643174/cancel-all-proximity-alerts/) but not available anymore

Comment: try locationManager.removeProximityAlert(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(arg0, 0, arg1, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

Comment: isnt that what the other answer said

Comment: no change, still notifies

Comment: yeah, im as stuck as you, ill look around though

Comment: the only way i found, was to unregister the receiver there like in onDestroy. but i guess this is not the optimal way

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the proximity alert after it fires and not recreate it again (save some flag, as a variable or, if you use sqlite, in your db).

Removing alerts is a bit tricky, there are 2 steps to take and both will produce the intended result of not (apparently) "firing":

1. Unregister your receiver

   You may save a receiver (or array of receivers) and `unregister` it directly:

   ```
   for (ProximityReceiver proximityReceiverLocal:proximityReceiverArray) {
       context.unregisterReceiver(proximityReceiverLocal);
       proximityReceiverArray.remove(proximityReceiverLocal); // clear pile
   }
   ```
2. Remove alerts

   Note: You cannot save an alert as an object, you must recreate your `PendingIntent` and submit it to its `removeProximityAlert` method.  The pending intent must have the same intent (i.e. same `action name`) and the same pending intent id:

   ```
   public void removeProximityAlert(int pendingIntentIdIn, String intentActionNameIn) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(intentActionNameIn);
       PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context , pendingIntentIdIn, intent, 0);
       locationManager.removeProximityAlert(pendingIntent);
   }
   ```

If you remove one and not the other, you will achieve your intended goal of nothing occurring when you enter the POI's radius, but you will be wasting precious battery life and memory.